# Are there simple examples of Banach spaces with no non-trivial Clifford Isometries?

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples, clifford-algebras

By a Banach space $X$ I mean, a complete normed vector space and by a Clifford isometry I mean a surjective isometry $\gamma$ of $X$ such that the distance $d(\gamma x, x)$ is constant on $X$.  Inherently, $\gamma$ acts as a "translation" so Clifford isometries are sometimes called Clifford translations. As an example, in Euclidean space any translation "is" a Clifford isometry.

My question is: are there examples of such an $X$ where the set of Clifford isometries consists only of the identity?

Comment: I don't understand: every translation in a normed space is a Clifford isometry, as $\|(x+v)-x\| = \|v\|$. Are you asking whether there are Clifford isometries that aren't translations?

Comment: Sure, just consider the vector space with one element $\{ 0 \}$. =)

Answer (score 1):

By [Mazur-Ulam theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) every surjective isometry is an affine map, i.e.
$$
\gamma(x)=x_0+T(x)
$$
for some fixed vector $x_0\in X$ and necessary isometric isomorphism $T\in\mathcal{B}(X)$.

Assume that surjective isometry $\gamma$ is a Clifford isometry, then we have $C\geq 0$ such that for all $x\in X$ we have 
$$
\Vert x_0+T(x)-x\Vert=C
$$
I think it's quite obvious that in this case $T$ is neccessary the identity map on $X$. Hence, every Clifford isometry is a translation on some vector $x_0\in X$.

Comment: Just a clarification. Having taken care of translation, we are left with a Clifford isometry that fixes $0$. It must be a linear operator, by Mazur-Ulam. For all $x$ we have $2\|Tx-x\|=\|T(2x)-2x\|=\|Tx-x\|$, hence $Tx=x$.

Comment: @Leonid, thanks! It is a bit easier.